# Reference for space-time finite element method

Tags: finite-element-method

I want to study about solving time dependent problems using fem. I have references for solving such problem by first discretizing the space domain and then applying finite difference scheme in time variable. Another way to solve time dependent problem is to use the space-time finite element. I am searching for references to understand space-time fem at very basic level. Any suggestion would be really helpful.